# How to create Apigee KVM

Tags: kvm, apigee

I am trying to create KVM for apigee but not sure. since I am new to apigee. Could anyone please guide how to create KVM (public/private) key pair?

Appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@harper
I would suggest using GitLab CI/CD pipeline to document your changes to the Apigee for your own comfort.
I'm using https://github.com/jhd235/apigee-config-maven-plugin for deployment.
Look into https://github.com/apigee/apigee-config-maven-plugin/blob/32b0e217d8088eeaa21559a68783916496ad4a4d/samples/EdgeConfig/edge.json#L107

thanks,
regards,
Yermek